# Modelo de aplicativo para .net standard library

Tags: c#, .net

No Visual Studio, eu sei que eu posso criar um modelo de aplicação do tipo UWP - Universal Windows Platform, onde o assistente põe por padrão referências as bibliotecas do .net core no projeto, dentre elas a .net standard. O .net framework dá suporte à .net standard 1.3, então os aplicativos UWP rodam no .net framework.
Mas, além do UWP (ou um modelo de console para aplicacões .net core) não existe a opção de de criar nenhum outro modelo. 
De que forma eu posso criar um aplicativo com Interface Gráfica de Usuário que rode no Linux, no macOS e no Windows (por meio da .net standard)?

Comment: Não é possível "Aplicativo com Interface Gráfica (nativa)"  `.netcore` `.net standard`. Aplicações web acredito que seja possível.

Comment: Sim. Claro. Mas, e se eu quiser implementar um aplicativo com o GTK# junto com .net standard library? não é possível?

Comment: Boa pergunta, até onde sei não é possível, vou me informar sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após muita pesquisa, concluo que a *.Net Standard Library* vem facilitar a construção multiplataforma desktop-mobile, mobile-mobile, e aplicações web poli-plataforma, tendo como único modelo de interface gráfica o *Windows Universal Platform*. A *.Net Standard Library* é um *subset* padrão de de APIs que deve estar presente em  todas versões da plataforma .Net existentes ou a serem implementadas.

Então, caso queira construir uma aplicação desktop multiplataforma com interface gráfica eu devo utilizar Biblioteca de Classes Base - BCL do .Net Framework que também é implementada pelo Projeto Mono e, por opção, o GTK#.